# What happened to the antielectrons and antiprotons and $\mu^-,\tau^-$ at the time of recombination?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

Recombination is the time when the Universe was made up of electrons $e^-$ and protons $p^+$ and the electrons attached to the protons to form the first hydrogen atom. What happened to the antielectrons $e^+$ and antiprotons $p^-$? Why we also do not talk about other particles such as $\mu^-,\tau^-$ etc?

Comment: At recombination there were no e+ or p-. $\mu$ and $\tau$ are unstable.

Comment: @my2cts yes $\mu$ and $\tau$ are unstable but will not be abundantly and continuously created at that temperature?

Comment: The temperature at recombination was around 4000K. This is far too low to create muons or tau particles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a history of the universe in the standard Big Bang model:

[image]

You are asking about the time of 380.000 years after the BB. By that time the baryon asymmetry , which is what your question is about, is manifest. It is mainly protons and electrons. Taus and muons are irrelevant to the asymmetry in  baryon number seen presently.

How this baryon asymmetry manifested itself in the previous eras is a matter of the particle physics model used , and it is still an open question , [here is a review](http://physics.ucsc.edu/~joel/Cosmology224/Lectures/08_224-L18-Baryogenesis.pdf), even from 2008  the situation is similar presently.

[A different plot](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html) of the history of the universe shows the ages where breaking of symmetry in unification of particle theories happens

[image: timeline]

Depending on the theoretical model, the violation of baryon number conservation could happen at the times of the symmetry breaking for the various unification processes.

Baryon number violation is an active area of research both in particle physics and in cosmological models.